# SQL: Return values of one column, only if on the same row another column has a distinct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, distinct

I'm working on an SQL Query, where I want to return values of one column, only if on the same row another column has a distinct value.

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

Table: Mix

```
ID           WEIGHT           
1           100             
1           100
2           150
2           150
2           150
3           200
```

What I want to be returned is:

```
ID          WEIGHT
1           100
2           150
3           200
```

Here is what I'm trying right now:

```
DECLARE @UNIQUE_INGREDIENT DECIMAL(10,3);

SET @UNIQUE_INGREDIENT = SELECT DISTINCT Mix.ID,
                                Mix.WEIGHT
                         FROM MixLot
```

How should I write the query to return the table I want?

Comment: You cannot set a single value to a table.  What you want to do is unclear.

Comment: I don't get it. `weight` isn't uniqe in any of the rows, at least if I interpret it as "no other row with the same value exists", but 1 and 2 are in the result. The desired result however holds the distinct values of the rows (i.e. the combination of all attributes). I'm left confused...

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You'd get the shown result with `select distinct * from mix`. Do you mean by the distinct value thing, that you'd exclude ID 1 if there was another row for it with a value different from 100?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. What I want to show is the weight, only if the ID is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd compare the minimal and maximal weight per id, and return only the rows where they are equal:

```
SELECT   id, MAX(weight)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING   MAX(weight) = MIN(weight)
```